# Why is there asymmetry in the metric coefficents of the spherical coordinate system. I am only looking for a hint.

Tags: calculus, physics

[image]

I am only asking for a hint, I do not understand the geometry of the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: _Asymmetry?_ Who would expect any symmetry in the first place? They have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0):

Let us fix $R$, and look at the sphere of radius $R$. If one fixe $\theta$ (i.e. the latitude), one gets a circle of length $2\pi. R. \sin (\theta)$ (or radius $R \sin(\theta)$. If one fixes t he longitude $\phi$, one gets a great circle of length $2\pi R$.